# How to check if a float value is within a certain range and has a given number of decimal digits?

Tags: python, floating-point

How to check if a float value is within a range (0.50,150.00) and has 2 decimal digits?

For example, 15.22366 should be false (too many decimal digits). But 15.22 should be true.

I tried something like:

```
data= input()
if data in range(0.50,150.00):
   return True
```

Comment: .... I don't think you understand how datatypes work. Regardless of how you represent it, a `float` will always store the same precision.

Comment: What does "check the validity of float" mean?

Comment: @LondonRob it means that, for example, i want to write a function where the parameters pass is a value, if the value is within that range (0.50,150.00) and with the 2decimal places, then i should return true, else i should return false.

Comment: Is the [[tag:random]] tag still relevant to that question?

Comment: @Sylvain Leroux no it is no longer relevant. Thank you

Comment: @user3841581 Check edits to my answer. Also, in future, please do not edit the original question so significantly that its meaning changes completely and some of the existing answers be rendered obsolete. Ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Is that you are looking for?

```
def check(value):
    if 0.50 <= value <= 150 and round(value,2)==value:
        return True
    return False
```

---

Given your comment:

> i input 15.22366 it is going to return true; that is why i specified the range; it should accept 15.22

Simply said, ***floating point* values are imprecise**. Many values don't have a precise representation. Say for example `1.40`. It might be displayed "as it":

```
>>> f = 1.40
>>> print f
1.4
```

[But this is an *illusion*](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html). Python has rounded that value in order to nicely display it. The real value as referenced by the variable `f` is quite different:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal(f)
Decimal('1.399999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375')
```

According to your rule of having only 2 decimals, should `f` reference a valid value or not?

The easiest way to fix that issue is probably to use `round(...,2)` as I suggested in the code above. But this in only an heuristic -- only able to reject "largely wrong" values. See my point here:

```
>>> for v in [ 1.40,
...            1.405,
...            1.399999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375,
...            1.39999999999999991118,
...            1.3999999999999991118]:
...     print check(v), v
...
True 1.4
False 1.405
True 1.4
True 1.4
False 1.4
```

Notice how the last few results might seems surprising at first. I hope my above explanations put some light on this.

---

**As a final advice, for your needs as I *guess* them from your question, you should definitively consider using "decimal arithmetic". Python provides the [decimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) module for that purpose.**

Comment: if i do this, i input 15.22366 it is going to return true; that is why i specified the range; it should accept 15.22(it should only accept folating point with two decimal places and within that range

Comment: @user3841581 I had the feeling there was something _like_ that. I made a large edit to answer you. Take some time to experiment with that, then, if needed, feel free to ask _an other question_ for clarification.

Comment: it does work on some case for more than 3 decimal places. but for a 1 decimal place floating point like 1.5, it still return true

Comment: @user3841581 huh? `1.4 == 1.40`. Maybe you should deal with string instead? As I suggested above, you **really** should take some time thinking more about your needs -- and definitively post an other question after that...

Comment: Minor niggle: Python's `decimal` module provides floating-point arithmetic, not fixed-point, though its treatment of significant trailing zeros makes it possible to simulate some aspects of fixed-point arithmetic.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux, thank you; for my application, it works just fine. Thank you again:)

Answer (score 3):

`float` is the wrong data type to use for your case, Use [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#module-decimal) instead.

Check [python docs for issues and limitations](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html). To quote from there (I've generalised the text in Italics)

> Floating-point numbers are represented in computer hardware as base 2 (binary) fractions.
>
> no matter how many base 2 digits you’re willing to use, *some decimal value (like 0.1)* cannot be represented exactly as a base 2 fraction.
>
> Stop at any finite number of bits, and you get an approximation
>
> On a typical machine running Python, there are 53 bits of precision available for a Python float, so the value stored internally when you enter a decimal number is the binary fraction which is close to, but not exactly equal to it.
>
> The documentation for the built-in round() function says that it rounds to the nearest value, rounding ties away from zero.

And finally, it recommends

> If you’re in a situation where you care which way your decimal halfway-cases are rounded, you should consider using the [decimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#module-decimal) module.

And this will hold for your case as well, as you are looking for a precision of 2 digits after decimal points, which float just can't guarantee.

---

**EDIT Note:** The answer below corresponds to original question related to random float generation

Seeing that you need 2 digits of sure shot precision, I would suggest generating integer random numbers in range `[50, 15000]` and dividing them by `100` to convert them to float yourself.

```
import random
random.randint(50, 15000)/100.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use `round`?

```
round(random.uniform(0.5, 150.0), 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably what you want to do is not to change the value itself. As said by [Cyber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2296458/cyber) in the comment, even if your round a floating point number, it will always store the same precision. If you need to change the way it is printed:

```
n = random.uniform(0.5, 150)
print '%.2f' % n               # 58.03
```

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way is to first convert the decimal to string and split with '.' and check if the length of the character. If it is >2 then pass on. i.e. Convert use input number to check if it is in a given range.

```
a=15.22366
if len(str(a).split('.')[1])>2:
    if 0.50 <= value <= 150:
        <do your stuff>>
```